# Can we draw a graph with only cycles of length 5 through 9 with only 9 vertices?.

Tags: graph-theory

Can we draw a graph with only 9 vertices with only cycles of length 5 through 9 ?

Draw a connected graph having exactly 9 vertices that has at least one cycle of each length from 5 through 9, but has no cycles of any other length.

Comment: Try it yourself first. Draw a $9$-vertex graph with a $9$-cycle, try adding some more edges to it to get the other cycles, and if you get stuck, *then* it will do you any good to ask for help.

Comment: It is easy for me to draw a 9-vertex graph with cycles of  length  5,6,7,9. But  I can not find a cycle of  length 8.

Comment: Hm. Maybe it is not possible.

Comment: can we prove it? It seems that it is impossible.

Comment: There's the casework approach I've outlined below. Maybe there's another argument possible, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both trying to find such a graph and proving that it does not exist can be done by casework.

Start with the $9$-cycle, since there is only one way it can look. We need to add more edges to get more cycle lengths, and all options so far are equivalent: we connect two vertices at distance $4$ around the cycle.

If we add an arbitrary one of these edges, then several other options can be eliminated since they'd create a short cycle. All our remaining choices are drawn in red below:

[image: edge options cycles]

Now, it is easy to check all the remaining cases, and none of them produce all five cycle lengths we want.